# VueJS - Disabling cache results in network request errors

Tags: .htaccess, caching, networking, browser, browser-cache

**EDIT** *This issue seems to only affect Chrome and Safari on my Macbook Pro. I can't replicate this issue on other computers and browsers. I thought it might have been malware or virus, so I reformatted my Macbook. Didn't fix the issue All of a sudden, I am running into this issue when developing on my local server as well with MAMP. Assets are missing everywhere and some pages fail to load all together*

I've noticed recently when I refresh my Vue SPA with the cache disabled, the page tends to look messed up with missing images/resources.

When I check the console, I see a lot of ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for resources that are definitely there. If I refresh the page, the errors go away. It tends to happen after I clear cache and load up the webpage for the first time, or if I disable cache in the developer console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there had recently been a DDos attack against my IP address so my hosting service forced rate limit connections to my IP address. So if you ever run into the same issues, check with your hosting company first.